# PictureBox background ignoring WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2013, user-controls

I want to create a Checkers Board with animation on tiles.

In order to do so I created a rectangle WPF UserControl to represent the tiles.

on top of the tiles I'm using a PictureBox with a picture of red/black piece.

when creating and adding the tiles and after that the PictureBoxes I can't see the PictureBoxes because they are behind the tiles.
(if I reverse the order of the creation and adding of the elements I see the pictures above the tiles but the transparent background of the PictureBoxes shows me the form background like it ignores the UserControl beneath it.

for better explanation I attached a photo (I set the form's background to green for better understanding)

[image: My Checkers Board]

also here are the code parts I think are relevant

the WPF UserControl (named UserControlCell) Xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Width="50"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"  Name="myRect"/>
</Grid>
```

Each tile is treated that way

```
ElementHost eh = new ElementHost();
UserControlCell square = new UserControlCell ;

square.Size = new Size(someWidth, someHeight);
eh.Size = new Size(someWidth, someHeight);

eh.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xCoordinate,yCoordinate);

if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
    square.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
else
    square.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

eh.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

eh.Child = square;

Controls.Add(eh);
```

and for each PictureBox

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
pb.Image = relevantImage;
pb.Size = new Size(someWidth, someHeight);
pb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xCoordinate,yCoordinate);
pb.TabStop = false;
pb.Visible = true;
pb.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
pb.Refresh();
Controls.Add(pb);
```

what could be the problem that causes the picture box to think that it's background is the form instead of the tiles (or why does adding them in opposite order making me not seeing the PictureBoxes at all)

Comment: Is there any reason why you are mixing WPF and WinForms? The UI seems trivial, so better create it using only WPF or WinForms, not both.

Comment: @Clemens It's the requirements for the exercise